# Customizing devise controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to change slightly the behaviour of one devise controller method. Here it says I can do that running rails generate devise:controller users.

However doing that just generated commented code with a bunch of super calls. If I don't know what the super methods do, how am I supposed to edit the lines of code I want to change?

The modification I want to do is simple: if there is no admin user yet (none with role=admin was found), then the user's role will be set to admin, else, it will be a normal user. So I thought in this case an after_filter would be the solution, so I did this:

```
class UserController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    after_filter :set_role, only: [:create]

    protected
    def set_role
        admin_user = User.find_by_role(User::admin_role)
        if admin_user.nil?
            @user.role = User::admin_role
        else
            @user.role = User::default_role
        end
        @user.save
    end
end
```

My routes:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { users: "users" }
```

However, the method is not even being executed. Why? What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to be overriding the registrations controller:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Then the controller:

controllers/registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    admin_user = User.find_by_role(User::admin_role)
    if admin_user.nil?
      resource.role = User::admin_role
    else
      resource.role = User::default_role
    end

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: how did you get the code for `RegistrationsController::create`? Because as I said, when generating the controllers with `rails g devise:controller users` I only got commented `super`s. Where can I find these methods (I guess you copied it from the source)?

Comment: Also, doing what you say returns this error `uninitialized constant RegistrationsController`

Comment: Yes mine was directly from the source (devise 3.0.3). Did you restart your server? Did you put it in the controllers directory? Not a subfolder within it?

Comment: (I rarely use generators which is why I used this approach)

Comment: Just looked at devise page, I think the generated controllers would work about the same, you could just copy my code into the users registrations controller 'create' action, removing the commented super.

Comment: When using the generators a `users` folder is created in the `controllers` folder, and in here `RegistrationsController`. I copied your code in this file, and I got that error.

Comment: Ok I edited the routes like this `devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }` However, when creating a user, the new method `create` is not being executed. I tested some `puts` in there and the log shows nothing, also the user's roles are null.

Comment: Go back to my original approach. routes to registrations: "registrations" and registrations_controller.rb in top level of controllers dir. I took my code from a live setup, so it works.

Comment: Ok I made it work, thanks. Now the role is not being saved in the database, but that's a different question.

Comment: Glad you got it working. If you can't solve link me to question here, but give it a try first :)

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020049/rails-and-devise-model-attribute-not-being-persisted